# Auto-hide a row based on a value in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

A column in my Excel spreadsheet contains a formula, which calculates to either 0 or 1. At the outset, all cells in that column have a value of 1.

I need to hide the entire row where cell value changes to 0, and then un-hide if the value changes back to 0.

Is there any way to achieve this? I would like the macro to run automatically; i.e. the rows hide or un-hide automatically as soon as the value changes.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Look in to the [`Worksheet_Change()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel) event.

Comment: If a formula changes the value, then you need to watch the actual input that causes the formula to recalculate, not the cell with the formula. Using the Event that Bruce Wayne mentions.

Answer (score 0):

*Should be something like this*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, [B:B]) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Rows.Hidden = UCase(Target.Value) = "0"
    End If
End Sub
```